# MAAS new Node Network and Storage error

Tags: 16.04, maas

OS: UBUNTU 16.04

MAAS: 2.0.0. Beta 3

I added one node it shows up as new , both network adopter connectet to network(One internal and one exteral), When I am looking at node pages on MAAS GUI, it says (Under **Interfaces**):

Node must be connected to a network.

And Under **Storage** segment it says:

No storage information. Commissioning this node will gather the storage information.
Specify a storage device to be able to deploy this node.
Mount the root '/' filesystem to be able to deploy this node.

Answer (score 2):

```
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04 LTS"
Installed: 2.0.0~beta3
```

1. First problem (Node must be connected to a network):

Visit the node details page for the node that is reporting "Node must be connected to a network".

On that page select the subnet you want the interface to DHCP from and then select "DHCP" in the IP assignment section.

2. I am also facing the same problem for the second one

My node commissioning is getting failed with following error.
Mount the root '/' filesystem to be able to deploy this node.
Earlier my hard disk was not getting detected. Now it is detected but MAAS is not able to deploy the node.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image: node deployment error]

Comment: I've the same problem. While if I create manually a VM via KVM console on HOST using as location the local dev and then adding it on MAAS i can complete all tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the standard image for **hwe-16.04-edge** and the commissioning step ran without problem.

Here is the error and set up.

Maas version: 2.3.0 (6434-gd354690-0ubuntu1~16.04.1) 
  Commissioning node manually I got this error

> *"Mount the root '/' filesystem to be able to deploy this node."*

.

**Storage setup**:

Hardware RAID

controller PERC H330 Mini

virtual disk one, raid1 278   GB

virtual disk two, raid5 1.3   TB

Previously for testing purpose I installed ubuntu server 16.04 in the virtual
  disk one (sda) and mounted the virtual disk two (sdb) without problems.

Login in the ephemeral image I got:

**lsblk**

> NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
>
> loop0    7:0    0 172.9M  0 loop /media/root-ro
>
> sda      8:0    0 278.9G  0 disk
>
> ```
> ├─sda1   8:1    0 277.9G  0 part 
> ├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
> └─sda5   8:5    0   975M  0 part
> ```
>
> sdb      8:16   0   1.4T  0 disk
>
> ```
> └─sdb1   8:17   0   1.4T  0 part
> ```

**fidsk -l**

```
    Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type

    /dev/sda1  *         2048 582842367 582840320 277.9G 83 Linux

    /dev/sda2       582844414 584841215   1996802   975M  5 Extended

    /dev/sda5       582844416 584841215   1996800   975M 82 Linux swap / Solaris

    /dev/sdb1        2048 2924216319 2924214272  1.4T 83 Linux
```